# How to download container blob into Azure App Service wwwroot?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage

I have a zip file in a container under an Azure Storage account.

I want to download this zip file as a pipeline task after the deployment of the .NET Core app to an Azure App Service slot (Azure DevOps). The front-end (index.html) of this app is in this zip file, which must be downloaded/extracted to the wwwroot.

I tried it with a `Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript` task but there is no wwwroot folder available as seen in the Kudu debugconsole of the App Service.

Is there a(n easier) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand the issue (you're deploying a webapp, then you want to download another zip from blob storage, and deploy that to the same webapp?), but I'll have a stab at it.

Deploy the webapp with Azure App Service Deploy task as normal.

Add an Azure PowerShell task, which will run on the Build Agent, not on the webapp, so it won't see the wwwroot folder.  It *can* however run Get-AzureStorageBlob to download the zip, save it locally in a local folder (like `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tmp` or something).

Have an Azure App Service Deploy deploy it `($(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tmp/*.zip`) up, just make sure that you haven't selected "Remove additional files at destination" when you do the second deploy or it *will* wipe the first site out.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I am deploying a .NET Core app, which will get its front-end (index.html) from this zip file, located in a azure storage container.